# useRef Typescript error: Property 'current' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-hooks

I'm making a Datepicker with React and Typescript, and I can't seem to get over the errors with `useRef` and the ref's `.current` property. I'm trying to get the `div` I'm assigning the ref to to close when the document is clicked outside of it.

I just can't quite seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
function Datepicker({label, placeholder}: DatepickerProps){
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [day, setDay] = React.useState(0)
  const [month, setMonth] = React.useState(new Date().getMonth())
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState(new Date().getFullYear())
  const picker = React.useRef(null) as HTMLElement | null

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", toggle)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", toggle)
    };
  }, []);

  const toggle = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (picker && picker.current){
      if (picker.current.contains(e.target) === false){
        setOpen(false)
      }
    }
  }

  //...

  return(
    
    //...

    <div 
      ref={picker}
      className={"datepicker-picker" + (open ? " open" : "")}
    >

      //...

  )
}
```

`React.useRef(null) as HTMLElement | null` is giving me the following problem:

```
Conversion of type 'MutableRefObject<null>' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more.ts(2352)
```

`.current` is giving me the following:

```
Property 'current' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

and when I try to apply the ref to a `div` element, its says the following:

```
Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined'.
    Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(143, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

I'm using VSCode as my IDE, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`useRef` does not return the value in the ref - asserting the type of the return value as `HTMLElement | null` is inaccurate. Use a generic type argument instead:

```
const picker = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

You'll also need to change `toggle` so that the type narrowing occurs as desired:

```
const toggle = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  const { current } = picker;
  if (current && !current.contains(e.target)) {
    setOpen(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: That helped with the first error and the last! (I used `HTMLDivElement` instead) Now it's giving me this error: `Argument of type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node | null'.` Also, my file is .tsx, am I allowed to do type assertions in the form of `useRef<HTMLElement>`?

Comment: It sounds like you need to assert that the event target is a Node: `e.target as Node`. *am I allowed to do type assertions in the form of* Sure, though that's not a type *assertion*, that's a type *parameter* passed to `useRef`. Such type parameters are just fine.

Comment: `ref={picker as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}`